# Laravel - getMimeType return wrong result on different server

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, laravel, mime-types

I upload an powerpoint file `.pptx` and submit

My controller file has this code to get the file mimetype.

`return Input::file('document')->getMimeType();`

on my Localhost - Xampp, i get correct result which is :

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`

But why when i deploy my code to production server, hosted at exabyte , 
the mimetype function return as

`application/zip` ?

can i know how to fix this issue? is it the php server related problem? or my code's problem?

Comment: A similar problem is found [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files) but the problem is server related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I purchased my Domain & server with Exabyte, I had contacted them and the issue is php's compiling issue, After they recompile the php to add fileinfo,everything was fine.!